# Can you run google app engine instances within a compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

No experience of this so simple question.

I want to create multiple app engine instances and host them on a compute engine. The main reason for want to use app engine is to access the api library whilst the reason for wanting to use a VM would be for each app engine instance to be able to share data with the other.

Comment: App Engine instances can share data with each other with no problems. No need for VM.

Answer (score 1):

Appengine have Managed VM instances. It's exactly what you're looking, Appengine [compatible] instances hosted on Compute Engine.

It's in beta, and lack of some Appengine features, but mostly works. It's less restricted than Appengine, have access to filesystem, network, threads, etc. You could install additional software, tune vm, etc.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

Comment: You mean Compute Engine can have managed app engine instances sharing resources and assets such as dbs and files.

Comment: anything, you can provide your Dockerfile with any extra stuff you want. but I suggest to have dbs/files on other machine, appengine instances supposed to be stateless, or it won't be scalable

Comment: I thought GAE was a web server platform and so surely I can code to turn on sessions and achieve statefulness for users that way.

Comment: App Engine instances can be shut down at any time and so you should store data *outside* of the VM.  So, yes, you can use App Engine Managed VMs to serve your application and 'turn on sessions' to persist state between requests, but you want to store that data in Datastore or a Cloud SQL db, for example.  If you just want the core App Engine API, you don't need managed VMs for that - you may want to use different modules (e.g., [java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)) which will all share the same Datastore data.